# Fastest way to loop through thousands of form elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through several thousand javascript elements. Specifically checkboxes and selects. The checkboxes need to be toggled between check/uncheck and selects need to disabled/enabled depending on whether a main checkbox is checked or not.

```
 <script>
 function processFormElem(min, max, isChecked) {
    for (var i=min; i < max; i++) {
        document.getElementById('chkbox_'+i).checked = isChecked;
        document.getElementById('select_'+i).disabled = !(isChecked);
    }
}
</script>

 Check this: <input onchange='processFormElem(0,10000,this.checked);' type='checkbox'  value = '0'><br/><br/>

 <?php
 for ($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
     echo "Check: <input type='checkbox' id='chkbox_$i' value = '1'> ";
     echo "Select: <select disabled='disabled'  id='select_$i'><option selected>1<option>xyz</select><br/>";
 }
 ?>
```

This code does what's needed but it's extremely slow in processing through the form elements, and I can notice the lag. Is there any way to make it faster ?

Comment: "I'm trying to loop through several thousand javascript elements" - Why?? "it's extremely slow" well yeah... "Is there any way to make it faster?" don't loop through several thousand elements.

Comment: Several thousand form elements? That sounds to me like a bit of a design flaw. Can you explain why you would need several thousand form elements on one page?

Comment: wow 10 thousand elements on a webpage? There is no way to speed that up considerably with that big of a loop in client side script

Comment: Maybe you could split the loop into smaller ones with using setTimeout/Interval.

Comment: Is this page used as an enhanced interrogation technique?

Comment: Fastest `for` you can get: [`for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Arrays)

Comment: Is it perhaps quicker to step through the `elements` array rather than querying the DOM for every form element?

Comment: @Derek: Yes, that would be the fastest, but it would also require copying all the elements into an array first, which in this case would be extremely slow.

Comment: @w3d: see my answer below; short answer: yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your checkboxes and select boxes are all immediately after one another, try using [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling). The problem is that document.getElementById has to search through each element in the DOM tree to find the one with the matching ID (although the underlying implementation might use hash tables or something to improve ID lookup performance)

Either way, using nextElementSibling lets you walk through the elements as you would through a tree, saving you seek time.

For example:

```
var cb = document.getElementById('chkbox_' + min),
    sb = document.getElementById('select_' + min);
while (cb !== null && sb !== null) {
    cb.checked = isChecked;
    sb.disabled = !isChecked;

    cb = cb.nextElementSibling;
    sb = sb.nextElementSibling;
}
```

---

EDIT:

As David notes below, not all browsers support nextElementSibling. You can hack around that using nextSibling.

Instead of:

```
cb = cb.nextElementSibling;
```

Do:

```
while(cb !== null && cb.nodeName != 'Element') { cb = cb.nextSibling; }
```

That being said, the browsers that don't support nextElementSibling are becoming less and less common every day, and the nextSibling solution comes with plenty of its own overhead. It's up to you (or potentially your boss) if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: Bear in mind that [some browsers don't implement `nextElementSibling`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t83).

Comment: @David: Excellent point; edited with an alternate backwards-compatible solution.

Comment: @Derek: He appears to be using pure javascript, not JQuery. And I promise that the next function is a thin wrapper around the solutions I propose above, except it has all that unnecessary JQuery overhead as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to use Jquery here like this:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function () {  
    this.checked = isChecked; 
});
//isChecked-true/false
```

Hope it will work fine.

Comment: This is going to be slower for several reasons: 1) standard JQuery overhead; 2) the selector is going to gather all matching elements into an array first (very slow); 3) function creation/closure overhead (adding variables from parent function to anonymous function's scope); 4) function evaluation overhead (you have to call the function, which is a step in and of itself)